# Producing points uniformly over a disk

Tags: geometry

How can I produce around $60$ to $100$ points somewhat uniformly (so a grid is fine) over a disk of radius $r$, such that I can input an integer $n$, to get the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the $n$th point $(x_n,y_n)$?

The functions $x_n$ and $y_n$, must be possible to calculate on an (advanced) calcualtor. A spiral of sorts will work if uniform

Comment: Fill a grid of step $2r/\sqrt n$ in the tile $[-r,r]\times[-r,r]$ and reject the points such that $x^2+y^2>r^2$. You will get about $n$ uniform points, of which about $20\%$ will be rejected.

Comment: Its not easy to reject them, I need an explicit enumeration, a simple function

Comment: Is it a problem to store them in an array ?

Comment: Yes, need simple function, like a spiral or something

Comment: Is it indiscreet to ask why ? And is the number of points known in advance ?

Comment: Number of points can be of your choosing in the range 60-100. I need this as input to a program that only accepts such explicit expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am right, a spiral $\rho=f(\theta)$ such that the area of the circle of radius $\rho$ grows linearly with $\theta$ achieves a uniform density. The angle step must be large to avoid patterns.

For example

$$\rho=\sqrt\theta$$

with a step of $43$ radians.

[image]

Comment: Very nice, exactly what I need

Answer (score 1):

A cool, geometric idea might be to work out the, say $75^{th}$ roots of $r$, the radius of your circle, all of which will be evenly distributed about your circle.

That is to say,

Consider $z \in \Bbb C$ with modulus $r = \lvert z\rvert$ and let $\omega_n$ be the $n^{th}$ root of $z$, letting $n$ range from $0$ to $74$. With $\theta$ the argument of $z$, we have each point $\omega_n$ determined by

$$\omega_n = r^{1/75}\left[\cos\left( \frac{\theta + 2n\pi}{75} \right) + i\sin\left(\frac{\theta +2n\pi}{75} \right) \right].$$

For a computer program, you could set this up and then simply need to ask for the input of $0 \leq n \leq 74$. Since all points are distributed evenly around the circle, you have what you need.

Comment: I am not sure that the resulting 2D point density is uniform.

Comment: What is meant by uniform? The OP simply says "somewhat uniform". Is exactly even distribution not uniform? Forgive me if I've misunderstood something!

Comment: He said uniform over a disk. This is not the same as uniform angularly.

Comment: Oh god, in his original post he says circle! *head in hands*